# load image using byte array in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the below method in my angular component:

```
   <li *ngFor="let item of list1._subList" onclick="SelectImage()" class="active">
              <img alt="img"  [src]="getImage(resp.data_values[0])| secure | async"
              />
              <p>{{generateDisplayImgName(item.values[0])}}</p>
            </li>



 getImage(ficname: string) {
     let obj: any;
     // remember 5th question represents the zip file name
    obj = {"fileName":StringUtil.extractSubstring(5,ficname.length,ficname),"zipFileName":this.something,"terminalTypeId":5}
    return this.projectService.extractStudioImage(this.id1,this.id2,this.id3,obj).subscribe((data)=>{

      let objectURL = 'data:image/png;base64,' + data;
      if(ficname.includes('jpg')){
        objectURL = 'data:image/jpg;base64,' + data;
      }
      console.log(objectURL);
      return objectURL;
    })
  }
```

Below is the code for my httpCLient.

```
  extractStudioImage(id1,id2,id3,json){
      const headers = new HttpHeaders();

      let params = new HttpParams();
      params = params.set('a1', id1);
      params = params.set('a2',id2);
      params = params.set('a3',id3);

      return this._http.post(ServerAddress.getInstance().getValue() + this.extractStudioPhotoUrl, json,{
        headers: headers,
        params:params,
      });
    }
```

I works because, I can see the images in Fiddler. Now the problem is angular keeps attempting to parse JSON (in this case the byte representation of my image). I am not explicitly trying to parse any json.

Using my chrome debugger: I see this:
It is an HttpResponseError

Unexpected token � in JSON at position 0

I don't see what is wrong in my approach.

Comment: I'm confused about where the attempted JSON parsing would happen in this above code. Is it right inside the above lines of code, or in `projectService.extractStudioImage`, which isn't shown?

Comment: I have added some information regarding the misunderstanding

Comment: Does the error indicate a line in your code? My problem with understanding what's going on is that there's nothing in the code shown that clearly invokes JSON parsing. Is there HttpClient code elsewhere, for instance, that isn't shown?

Comment: The error does not indicate a line in my code but rather a parsing error in the request/response pipeline. vendor.js and pollyfills.js. It is out of my reach.

Comment: There is an HtttClient request going on somewhere, however, right? Because that's the most likely place for this error to be happening. I believe Angular assumes JSON as a default when doing a `get`.

Comment: I am doing a post and have not set the content-type header because I would be handling images in byte form

Comment: The same issue applies to the default for POST, as the answer someone else provided below indicates. Without specifying `responseType`, `post` will try to parse the server's response as JSON.

Answer (score 1):

You get this error because the `http` module you're using in your service expect `json` response type by default.

You need to tell it to accept "blob", and probably add the `Accept: image/png` header as well.

```js
extractStudioImage(id1,id2,id3,json) {
  const headers = new HttpHeaders();
  headers.append("Accept", "image/png");
  
  let params = new HttpParams();
  params = params.set('a1', id1);
  params = params.set('a2',id2);
  params = params.set('a3',id3);

  return this._http.post(ServerAddress.getInstance().getValue() + this.extractStudioPhotoUrl, json,
    {
      responseType: "blob",
      headers: headers,
      params: params
  });
}
```

and the create the url from the blob in your component:

```js
getImage(ficname: string) {
   let obj: any;
   // remember 5th question represents the zip file name
  obj = {"fileName":StringUtil.extractSubstring(5,ficname.length,ficname),"zipFileName":this.something,"terminalTypeId":5}
  return this.projectService.extractStudioImage(this.id1,this.id2,this.id3,obj).subscribe((data)=>{

    const objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(da);
    console.log(objectURL);

    return objectURL;
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that problem is solved. The image is not showing up.

Comment: @NesanMano so above would, i suspect, return an actually byte array, you would also probably need to then convert said byte array to a base64 string.

Comment: @NesanMano I've updated my comment, to use "blob" instead and add component example

Comment: @lezhumain It is simply not working. I have even followed this tutorial: https://medium.com/techinpieces/blobs-with-http-post-and-angular-5-a-short-story-993084811af4

Comment: @NesanMano What error do you get? Can you see both the ReQuest and Response from the HTTP call to get the image ?

Comment: @lezhumain I have solved the problem. I am using blob and evnt.target.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.

I the HTML section, I simply do this:

`<img alt="img" [id]="generateDisplayImgName(resp.data_values[0])" #refEl [src]="loadImageFromLocalStorage(generateDisplayImgName(resp.data_values[0]),refEl)"`

```
 getImage(ficname: string){
     let obj: any;

     // remember 5th question represents the zip file name
      obj = {"fileName":ficname,"zipFileName":this.c._list.filter(a=>a.qN===5)[0].answer,"typeId":5}
      this.projectService.extractStudioImage(this.a,this.b,this.c,obj).subscribe((data:Blob)=>{

        this.createImageFromBlob(ficname,data);
        return this.imageBlobUrl;
    });
  }

  createImageFromBlob(ficname:any , image: Blob) {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener("load", (evt) => {
      let res = evt.target.result;

      // Store Data URL in localStorage
      try {
        if (typeof res === "string") {
          localStorage.setItem(ficname, res);
          this.dixieDbService.addNewImage("giobu"+ficname, res).then(r => console.log("inserted: "));
        }
      }
      catch (e) {
        console.log("Storage failed: " + e);
      }
    }, false);
    if (image) {
      reader.readAsDataURL(image);
    }
  }
```

The technic is to use blob and handle it using try/catch as well as events. This is because we simply want to await for the incoming stream.

Comment: You also mentioned to use blob. I have to avoid making multiple requests to the server. In order to implements that, I had to use the and indexedDB. This is widely used by many big tech firms.

Comment: I don't think storing image is the `localStorage` is widely used at all (just look at your localStorage in any website, you'll never find any image in there). This is usually done by making use of HTTP caching. Anyway I'm glab youy found your solution, although still very intrigued in what didn't work with mine

Comment: localstorage was just a try. My solution is to use the indexedDB. I am having an issue with that. I would really appreciate that if you  can  take a look : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70818486/indexed-database-using-dexie-not-created/70819566?noredirect=1#comment125215037_70819566