# Indexed database using Dexie not created

Tags: angular, typescript, indexeddb, dexie

I have a angular app where I am trying to insert into an indexed Database.
The problem is that the database is not getting created.

Below is a section of the code where I insert an entry into the database.

```
  createImageFromBlob(ficname:any , image: Blob) {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener("load", (evt) => {
      let res = evt.target.result;

      // Store Data URL in localStorage
      try {
        if (typeof res === "string") {
          localStorage.setItem(ficname, res);
          this.dixieDbService.addNewImage(ficname, res).then(r => console.log("inserted: "));
        }
      }
      catch (e) {
        console.log("Storage failed: " + e);
      }
    }, false);
    if (image) {
      reader.readAsDataURL(image);
    }
  }
```

Below is bd.ts

```
import Table = Dexie.Table;
import Dexie from "dexie";

export interface ImageList {
  id?: number;
  imgName: string;
  imgDataUrlValue: string|ArrayBuffer;
}


export class AppDB extends Dexie {
  imageList!: Table<ImageList, number>;


  constructor() {
    super('ngdexieliveQuery');
    this.version(3).stores({
      imageList: '++id'
    });
   // this.on('populate', () => this.populate());
  }
  
}

export const db = new AppDB();
```

Below is the service class:

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {liveQuery} from "dexie";
import {db, ImageList} from "../dixie/db";

@Injectable()
export class DixieIndexedDbService {

  imageList$ = liveQuery(() => db.imageList.toArray());
  listName = 'My local image list';

  async addNewImage(imgName:string, imgDataVal:any) {
    await db.imageList.add({
      imgName: imgName,
      imgDataUrlValue:imgDataVal
    });
  }

  async getImgDataValue(imgName:string) {
    return db.imageList.get({imgName: imgName});
  }


}
```

I have the sample working code on stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-znzhv8

Comment: how did you solve it?

Comment: I have the same issue, how did you solve?

Answer (score -1):

With no options provided while invoking the constructor of `Dexie`, for the database to be created ...

1. Either issue a call to `open`
2. Or, issue a query to the database. For this to happen in the case above(OP), inside function `createImageFromBlob`, `load` event handler should have been invoked, calling `DexieService` method which in turn should be issuing a query on the database as part of the specified implementation. Post which, we should have a database.

---

`AppDB` class with a call to `open`...

```
import Table = Dexie.Table;
import Dexie from "dexie";

export interface ImageList {
  id?: number;
  imgName: string;
  imgDataUrlValue: string|ArrayBuffer;
}


export class AppDB extends Dexie {
  imageList!: Table<ImageList, number>;


  constructor() {
    super('ngdexieliveQuery');
    this.version(3).stores({
      imageList: '++id'
    });
    this.open(); // <---- Missing in OP
   // this.on('populate', () => this.populate());
  }
  
}

export const db = new AppDB();
```

Comment: It does not work. I am not even supposed to do . Dexie does everything for me. Open is actually to open an existing schema.

Comment: Not sure why it doesn't work, as when I tried it did. The `AppDB` provided in the OP doesn't work as is.

Comment: And I tried with version `3.2.0`.

Comment: Even a [link](https://jsfiddle.net/3tf5r0cu/) from their documentation is with a call to [open](https://dexie.org/docs/Dexie/Dexie.open())

Comment: As per the spec of `open`, **By default, db.open() will be called automatically on first query to the db**. The `AppDB` in the OP doesn't have a query as well.

Comment: So either you should be putting a call to `open` or issue a query on the database.

Comment: Not sure why you marked it as `not useful`. :-(